# bind9 logs; resolver priming query (5/ minute)

Tags: dns, bind

I am running bind9 on two 19.04 hosts and each has logs flooded with this error. Both are working well enough: the only issue is the fat logs.

The error message is the same, but the `named` source line number is different:

On one:

```
named[20436]: resolver priming query complete
```

and on the other:

```
named[1110]: resolver priming query complete
```

This appears off and on as a bug in bind9 and so though this version is not specifically mentioned as buggy

```
bind9-host/disco-updates,disco-security,now 1:9.11.5.P1+dfsg-1ubuntu2.5 amd64
```

That may be the issue.

This link suggests a temporary fix, but I don't understand it.

https://kb.isc.org/docs/aa-01537

Can someone explain, give example?

Answer (score 3):

Ran into this myself and had to work through to resolve it.  I kept getting those messages in the logs until I forced a resolution of each root resolver in order.  Even a reboot of the server wouldn't stop the messages once they started.  By the way, my root issue was that after a power loss IPv6 did not come back up properly, which apparently is a known issue for causing this bug to manifest.  See a detailed explanation of this issue on [isc.org](https://kb.isc.org/docs/aa-01309).

I used the tool 'dig' for resolving each server on ubuntu.  All I did was execute:

```
dig -t ANY A.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
```

for each of the root servers, A through M.  Using bash you can run this command to query each root server:

```
dig -t ANY {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M}.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
```

And finally the logs were no longer filling up with messages.  Hope that helps someone.  :)

Comment: Worked perfectly on Raspberry Pi.

Comment: worked for me too. I was migrating my LAN DNS server from an old CentOS to Ubuntu 20 with bind9, and disabling ipv6 completely. Thanks for the solution, very helpful